# C Struct typedef and declaration causing pointer errors

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, struct

I've tried and distill the following code as much as possible:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct item{
    struct item *next;
}item;

void addItem(item *list)
{
    item *newItem = list;
    while(newItem->next != NULL){
        newItem = newItem->next;
    }

    newItem->next = malloc(sizeof(item));
    newItem->next->next = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    item *groceryList = NULL;
    groceryList = malloc(sizeof(item));
    if(groceryList == NULL)
        return 1;
    groceryList->next = NULL;

    addItem(groceryList);

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine. But changing the struct declaration to (or any combination of the changes):

```
typedef struct{ /*Removed "item"*/
    item *next; /*Removed "struct"*/
}item;
```

Causes the following errors when compiling:

> structpointertest.c:11:11: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
>   structpointertest.c:15:15: error: request for member 'next' in something not a structure or union

I don't understand what in the struct declaration is causing this issue? Does it have something to do with the fact I'm using a nested struct?

Thanks.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know what `item` is at the declaration line `item *next`.

Comment: There is no "nested structure". And there cannot be without endless recursion.

Comment: Sorry, I worded it badly. I didn't mean a nesting of structures, but rather a nesting of aliases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C you must declare things before you can use them. When you do

```
typedef struct item { ... }
```

the `struct item` part is a declaration telling the compiler that there exists a structure name `item`. That means you could use it later, even inside the structure to define a pointer to itself.

When you do

```
typedef struct { ... } item;
```

you are not giving the structure a name, and the type-alias `item` is declared *after* the structure, so it can't be used inside the structure.

The simple solution is to use the first way. Another solution is to declare the type-alias before the structure, like

```
typedef struct item item;
struct item
{
    item *next;  // Can use type-alias, as it has been declared up above
};
```

Either way, you must still give the structure itself a name.

Also note that `struct item *next;` (or `item *next;`) declares a member variable that is a *pointer* to the structure, it's not the actual structure itself nested recursively. Creating a pointer to something that haven't been fully defined yet is okay.

Comment: Your last paragraph was bad wording by me.

Comment: Gah, new to the site, Enter in a comment is bad! Anyway, Thank you. I see now in what order the typedef is defined.

Comment: +1 because i tried to create a pointer to something that haven't been fully defined yet ... and surprisingly it works! I didn't know that

Comment: Best/easiest ways is `typedef struct ITEM {...} item;` (Use capitals in the struct tag namespace to distinguish from typedef namespace.)